# Homebrewing a Weapon in D&DBeyond for a campaign

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, homebrew, dnd-beyond

I received a custom magic weapon in our last campaign, and I want to build it in D&D Beyond so its effects can be used more automatically online/in virtual table tops. The name of it is *Ice Blink Warhammer*.

It does an additional 1d4 of cold damage on a Nat 20, and on a failed CON save the target loses half their movement. I have figured out how to apply the cold damage (though not necessarily the automatic trigger).

How would I build in the movement penalty effect? Or is it just not possible to do these effects as they do for native in-game items?

Answer (score 9):

### This can only be done via item description

If you want an effect that is gated by a roll of 20, you can enter a modifier with the Restriction "20 on the Attack Roll", as shown here (this is from the Longsword of Sharpness that deals extra damage on a nat 20).

[image: Effect on Nat 20]

While there is the possibility to add a modifier of type "Speed Reduction", and Modifier Subtype "Impose", there is no way to automatically tie this to either a saving throw, or to define that reduction in terms of the creatures speed.

Other game effects that slow down, like Ray of Frost, do something simpler, they just impose a speed reduction of a fixed value. (As many creatures have a speed of 30, you could try 15).

However, if you look how Ray of Frost is implemented (screenshot below), you can see that this speed reduction is not set up as an automatic effect even for native game elements, it is just mentioned in the description. The only modifier listed for it is the damage. I think if there was a way to make this an automatically imposed effect on a hit, that would have been implemented. So all you can do is mention is in the description, as *Ray of Frost* does.

[image: Screenshot of Ray of Frost implementation]

As a note, if you will want to set a DC for the Constitution Saving Throw that has the speed reduction effect, and your language should make it clear if the target needs to save on any hit, or only in case of a roll of 20 on the attack roll.

Comment: Thank you! This is helpful, and confirms what I had been running into.